# Difference between Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 RT NavigationCacheMode

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

Does Windows Phone 8 NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled is same as windows 8 RT NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled?
if so then, will page that we navigate back to, is created again (constructor is called) in windows phone 8?
if page is created again then how could i reproduce this scenario in simulator (in case of wp8) ?

Comment: When navigating forward to a page then constructor is called every time on phone and tablet both. But when going back to the previous page then on tablet the constructor  is called, but on phone its not called. Can you please explain this difference? Is it possible that on phone, when memory becomes low on the system then on going back, the construct is then called on the phone? or constructor will never be called on navigating back on phone?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i am aware, this does not exist in wp8. There are two ways of controlling this behavior,

1) Call any code that you wish to run every time the page loads in the On page navigated to event, as opposed to calling it in the constructor of the page. The "LoadDataFromOnNavigatedTo()" method below will always get executed when the page loads (including from lock screen)

```
 // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Loaded from constructor");
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data Loaded from onnavigated to");
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
```

2) Preferred option is to use an IoC container, such as the one provided in MVVMLight, and take control of when your ViewModels are instantiated. Then you can choose to instantiate them once and re-use application wide scoped, or in a transient way.

Comment: Be aware: OnNavigatedTo will be called on first load and return visits.

Comment: We are loading data in onNavigatedTo() and we don't want the data to fetch again and again, every time onNavigatedTo is called. Our question is, if we have a situation in which we encounter low memory issue then can Windows Phone OS delete some pages in the back stack? and when user navigate back, that page will be created again and we need to load its data again? Or OS will never delete a page in the backstack on windows phone?